# Changing elements of matrix in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix

I try to set a tictactoe game in python. I created a dynamic sized matrix but when I try to change elemnen of it the result didn't change. I want to set Player 1 as "X" and Player 2 as "O". Here is my codes:

```
def SetTable(matrix, size):
for i in range(size):
    for j in range(size):
        print("%4s" % (matrix[i][j]), end="")
    print()


matrix = []
size = int(input("Enter the Game Board Size:"))
for i in range(size):
   matrix.append([])
for j in range(size):
    matrix[i].append(i * size + j)
SetTable(matrix, size)



def p1secim(number):
   row = number // size
   column = number % number
   if matrix[row][column] != "X":
       matrix[row][column] == "X"
       print(matrix)
   else:
       print("You played this cell before!")


   hucre = int(input("player 1 turn-->"))

   p1secim(hucre)
```

Comment: Can you provide a little bit clarity on what you expect to be done?

Comment: I want to set a dynamic game  board. When player 1 play, "X" will be assigned and board will be printed after that player 2 play, "O" will be assigned and board will be printed again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the `p1secim` function that stand out and might give you a clue of what is not working. I am commenting below:

```
def p1secim(number):
    row = number // size
    column = number % number    # this will always return 0
    if matrix[row][column] != "X":
        matrix[row][column] == "X"    # This is a comparison and I think should
                                      # be an assignment: use '=' instead of '=='
        print(matrix)
    else:
        print("You played this cell before!")
```

There are likely other things to fix: overall, the code looks a bit unclear to me, so my suggestion would be to workout the logic and pieces carefully one by one.

Maybe you omitted for clarity, but there's no code handling the 'O' player; there's no loop to print the game board after each player makes a selection, win/lose logic etc...

Answer (score -1):

@sal already gave you some hints to correct your code, I will give you the entire solution!

```
import numpy as np

size = int(input("Enter the Game Board Size:"))

#size = 5
charar = np.chararray((size, size))
charar[:] = '_'

print(charar)

def p1secim(board):
    number = int(input("P1: "))
    if board[0, number] != '_':
        print('column alredy filled, chose another column!')
        p1secim(board)
    for i in range(size-1,-1,  -1):
        print('checking ' + str((i, number)))
        print(board[i, number])
        if board[i, number] == '_':
            board[i, number] = 'X'
            break
    print(board)

def p2secim(board):
    number = int(input("P2: "))
    if board[0, number] != '_':
        print('column alredy filled, chose another column!')
        p2secim(board)
    for i in range(size-1, -1,  -1):
        print('checking ' + str((i, number)))
        print(board[i, number])
        if board[i, number] == '_':
            board[i, number] = 'O'
            break
    print(board)

while True:
    p1secim(charar)
    p2secim(charar)
```

Comment: Thank you! It's very kind of you!